# How to add a specific post build action in jenkins for multiple jobs in one shot?

Tags: apache, jenkins, containers, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I need to add a post-build action(Deploy to container) to 23 jobs at a time. Is there a plugin to do that to make my work easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions:

- Either you update the post-build actions for each Job
- Either you are able to script your post-build action using Postbuildscript's plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript And you call this script in your post-build action

Benefit of the second solution, is that you will have to update your job's configuration only once. Then you only need to maintain your script.